# Listener callback variables static

Tags: c#

I have a callback for a listener such as

```
private static void OnOffering (string name, string number)
{
    string message = number + "called";
}
```

However the string `message` never gets the string "called" concatenated to it. The value of `number` is all that is assigned.

Anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: Maybe the compiled optimized this away, since you are discarding the result of the concatenation anyway?

Comment: Put a break point on the code (F9) and see if you reach the code.  The code isn't a callback method so it must be called by the callback method.  Is the callback method register?  Is the callback event occurring?  You have to do some debugging and really find out what is really happening.

Comment: This is just a method. You need to show the code which uses this method and also show whether this method is doing anything with the `message` variable.